# ClassNotFoundException is thrown on attempt to start RMI server in a web service running under Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, rmi, zimbra

I know it is a common question, but after reading a dozen of similar ones on SO and a lot of tries I still can't solve my problem.

I want to start RMI in Zimbra (8.6.0, jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505) web service extension.

The server interface class is located inside the service extension jar

```
$ jar -ft /opt/zimbra/lib/ext/addserver/addserver.jar | grep AddServer
com/gussy/zimbra/TestAddServer.class
com/gussy/zimbra/TestAddServerIntf.class
```

I tried to set java options via `zmlocalconfig`, like

```
zmlocalconfig -e zimbra_zmjava_options="-Xmx256m -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///opt/zimbra/lib/ext/addserver/addserver.jar"
```

and tried

```
export CLASSPATH=/opt/zimbra/lib/ext/addserver/addserver.jar && zmmailboxdctl restart
```

also tried to setup java options from inside java code

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "file:///opt/zimbra/lib/ext/addserver/addserver.jar");
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly", "false");
```

But can't fix the problem.

TestAddService.java

```
import com.zimbra.cs.extension.ExtensionHttpHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class TestAddService extends ExtensionHttpHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAddService.class);

    public TestAddService() {
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        TestAddServer testAddServer = new TestAddServer();
        Naming.rebind("TestAddServer", testAddServer);
    } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error(null,e);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
    return "/testadd";
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException, ServletException {}
}
```

TestAddServer.java

```
package com.gussy.zimbra;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class TestAddServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements TestAddServerIntf {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3527439814680102697L;

    protected TestAddServer() throws RemoteException {}

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
    return a + b;
    }
}
```

TestAddServerIntf.java

```
package com.gussy.zimbra;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface TestAddServerIntf extends Remote {
    int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Exception

```
2016-03-30 12:47:10,601 ERROR [main] [] TestAddService - 
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gussy.zimbra.TestAddServerIntf (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:420)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at com.gussy.zimbra.TestAddService.<init>(TestAddService.java:25)
    at pro.prokator.zimbra.ext.casem.SubscriptumExtension.init(SubscriptumExtension.java:53)
    at com.zimbra.cs.extension.ExtensionUtil.initAll(ExtensionUtil.java:116)
    at com.zimbra.cs.util.Zimbra.startup(Zimbra.java:263)
    at com.zimbra.cs.util.Zimbra.startup(Zimbra.java:178)
    at com.zimbra.soap.SoapServlet.init(SoapServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1359)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DebugHandler.doStart(DebugHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1250)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gussy.zimbra.TestAddServerIntf (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gussy.zimbra.TestAddServerIntf (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:556)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1559)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Is this the real code? Normally with that stack trace I would expect to see that you are running the Registry in a separate process. Try `registry.rebind()` instead of `Naming.rebind()`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, that is real code. Just tried with `registry.rebind()` - the same result.

Comment: No, this is not the real code. The exception is being thrown by `TestAddService`, and you haven't posted any such code.

Comment: Apologies, I renamed `TestAddService` class to `TestServiceExtension` in order for it not to be confused with `TestAddServer` (just before asking the question). I've just reverted that change.

Comment: I still don't believe this is the real code, for the reasons given in my answer. It simply isn't possible. Maybe you're not running the code version you think you're running.

Comment: I'm sorry I've made that mistake, I know you wasted your time and now still don't believe this is the real code. 
But can you please explain to me what and why is not possible?
BTW, I didn't want to run `registry` as separate process, but now this idea doesn't look so bad.
One more note, I'm not sure it is important, but just in case, here is Zimbra classloader parenting relationship (2nd paragraph) https://git.zimbra.com/repos/zimbra-foss/ZimbraServer/docs/extensions.md

Comment: If the Registry is in the same JVM that exports a remote interface that implements a remote interface, the remote interface is available on the classpath to both the remote object and the Registry. No two ways about that. I would be interested to see the stack trace when you used `registry.rebind()`. Edit it into  your question. But in general there is too much post-editing of the question to agree with the observations for anyone to have any confidence in any of it. Not to mention that what you describe isn't possible.

Comment: Wooops... Just retested it again, a couple of times with `Naming.rebind` and a couple of times with `registry.rebind` and the last one doesn't produce the exception, whereas the first one still throws it. Possibly I was too tired when I tested it the previous time. Please amend your answer by adding `registry.rebind` info and I'll accept it. BTW, what difference between  these two rebinding methods?

Comment: The only difference is that `registry.rebind()` isn't an RMI call if `registry` is the result returned by `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`: it's a local method call. I don't consider that part of the answer by itself. What this test seems to show is that there are two Registries, and that you're creating the local Registry on a different port than 1099, and using `Naming.bind()` talks to the external Registry on 1099, and using `registry.bind()` talks to the in-JVM one you created yourself. All these deviations from what should happen continue to reinforce that this is not the real code.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. The Registry doesn't have the class mentioned on its CLASSPATH.
2. This can only happen when you run the Registry as a separate process.
3. This not the real code. The exception is thrown by `TestAddService`, which you haven't posted.
4. The simplest solution is to run the Registry in your JVM, as per the code you did post, which can't possibly throw this exception.